# MySQL SELECT From Current Session User

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP and have session_start(); and $_SESSION['username'] at the top of the page. The user is logged in just fine.

The problem is, I am trying to pull and display data from just the user that is logged on. Below is my current query and it is pulling from the first user in the table, not $_SESSION['username'] user. How do I adjust SELECT to specify to pull from the current logged on user? Thanks.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members")
or die(mysql_error());  

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

echo "<strong>bio:</strong> ".$row['bio'].'<br />';
```

Comment: This is trivial. You should read up on SQL.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM members WHERE some_id_field = something_in_your_session`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = "'
  . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . '"')
  or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

You should read up on SQL and while you're at it, learn about SQL injections.

Comment: What do I put for the ' symbol next to username?

Comment: What do you mean? What symbol? You just typed in the symbol you're asking about, no?

Comment: I mean, what should I put for username = so it pulls from the current session user? Thanks for your help and yes and I am in the process of learning mysql... I'm also trying to learn it by simply doing it and reading the website documentation

Comment: advice "learn about SQL injections" + but using plain session variable in example code = you are doing it wrong

Comment: If you have a session variable `$_SESSION['username']` then the code I posted in my answer should work...

Comment: No luck, it says mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: @knittl I wanted to give the asker a simple example, all the while making sure they wouldn't stop there.

Comment: Fealia, you should add code for error handling to your queries. I updated my answer. Try that and it should tell you what the error is.

Comment: Notice: Unknown column 'testuser123' in 'where clause'

Comment: You need to specify the field name. `WHERE fieldname = value`. In your case, your field name is whatever you call the users in your table, probably `username`. If that doesn't work, update your question with your new code. Also post your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [WHERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) clause. It should be explained in the first chapter of any SQL manual:

```
SELECT foo, bar
FROM members
WHERE members_id=31416
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [SQL `WHERE` clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29).

Answer (score 0):

you need to supply a WHERE clause to your query specifying which data you wish to retrieve. Xeon06 is right, this is SQL 101.